# What is the opinion of Chofetz Haim on speech of Joseph about his brothers

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, yosef, lashon-hara-slander

Can you please quote how Chofetz Haim defined "diba ra" that Joseph said about his brothers.

Since it was not true, was it  real "motzi shem ra"? If not, why?

Joseph thought that he was saying the truth, but objectively it was not truth. What is halachic definition of his speech?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! This question would be much improved if you'd [edit] into it why you think its truth or falsehood would affect whether he's called _motzi shem ra_. Also if you would clarify [which Joseph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph) you're talking about, and where he spoke _diba ba_. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you want the Chofetz Chaim's opinion, specifically

Answer (score 1):

The Chafetz Chaim in Sefer Shmiras Halashon mentions Yosef's tattling on his brothers multiple times and treats it as a sin.

In Part I, Ch.9 - [פרק ט' - רוע עניינו לעתיד לבוא](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01605.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2) - he calls it slander and claims Yosef was reincarnated to atone for this sin.

> יוֹסֵף הַצַּדִּיק **הוֹצִיא דִּבָּה** עַל אֶחָיו וְנִתְגַּלְגֵּל בְּחָסִיד אֶחָד‏

---

In Part II, Ch. 3 - [פרק ג' - פרשיות בתורה המדברות בעניין זה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01605.html#HtmpReportNum0053_L2) - he says that Yosef's tattling to his father was the first reason we went into Egyptian exile.

> וּבְפָרָשַׁת וַיֵּשֶׁב, בְּמַעֲשֵׂה דְּיוֹסֵף, שֶׁכָּתוּב {בראשית ל''ז ב'}: ''וַיָּבֵא יוֹסֵף אֶת דִּבָּתָם רָעָה אֶל אֲבִיהֶם'', **שֶׁזּוֹ הָיְתָה הַסִּבָּה הָרִאשׁוֹנָה לִירִידַת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל לְמִצְרַיִם**.‏

---

In Ch. 11 - [פרק י''א - פרשת וישב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01605.html#HtmpReportNum0061_L2) - he says that the Torah brings the entire story of Yosef's tattling to his father, in order to teach us how important it is to watch what we say, as his speech had terrible consequences.

> הִנֵּה עִנְיַן יוֹסֵף עִם אֶחָיו. הֶאֱרִיכָה הַתּוֹרָה מְאֹד בְּסִפּוּר הָעִנְיָן אוֹדוֹתָיו וְאוֹדוֹת אֶחָיו, וְנִתְגַּלְגֵּל הַדָּבָר מִזֶּה סִבַּת יְרִידָתוֹ לְמִצְרַיִם, וְעוֹד כַּמָּה עִנְיָנִים נוֹרָאִים, שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּלְשְׁלוּ עַל יְדֵי זֶה, כְּדֵי **שֶׁמִּזֶּה יִקַּח כָּל אָדָם מוּסָר אֵיךְ שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לִשְׁמֹר פִּיו וּלְשׁוֹנוֹ**. ‏

He goes into great detail at this point, including explaining that despite Yosef's intention that his father should rebuke them, this was wrong and he should have rebuked them first by himself.

> ''וַיָּבֵא יוֹסֵף אֶת דִּבָּתָם רָעָה אֶל אֲבִיהֶם'' {בראשית ל''ז ב'}. שֶׁאָמַר, שֶׁהָיוּ קּוֹרִין לַאֲחֵיהֶם עֲבָדִים וְשֶׁחֲשׁוּדִים עַל הָעֲרָיוֹת וְשֶׁחֲשׁוּדִים עַל אֵיבָר מִן הַחַי. וְהִנֵּה הַכָּתוּב סִפֵּר לָנוּ, שֶׁלֹּא דִּבֵּר זֶה לְשׁוּם אָדָם, רַקּ לַאֲבִיהֶם, וְ**כַוָּנָתוֹ הָיְתָה כְּדֵי שֶׁיּוֹכִיחֵם אָבִיו, וְאַף עַל פִּי כֵן עָשָׂה שֶׁלֹּא כַּהֹגֶן, שֶׁהָיָה לוֹ לְהוֹכִיחָם בְּעַצְמוֹ מִתְּחִלָּה עַל זֶה**, שֶׁדִּין הוֹכָחָה הוּא אֲפִלּוּ תַּלְמִיד לְרַב, וְלֹא לְגַלּוֹת לְאָבִיו. וְאֶפְשָׁר שֶׁהָיוּ מוֹדִין לוֹ בְּמַה שֶׁקּוֹרִין לָהֶם עֲבָדִים, שֶׁלֹּא כַּדִּין הוּא, כִּי בֶּאֱמֶת יַעֲקֹב קֹדֶם שֶׁנְּשָׂאָן שִׁחְרְרָן וּלְקָחָן לְנָשִׁים, כְּמַאֲמַר הַכָּתוּב {בראשית ל''ז ב'}: ''נְשֵׁי אָבִיו'', אוֹ שֶׁהָיוּ מַרְאִין לוֹ עַל עֶצֶם הַחֲשָׁד, שֶׁטָּעוּת הוּא. וּמַה שֶּׁאָמַר שֶׁחֲשׁוּדִים עַל הָעֲרָיוֹת, טָעוּת הָיְתָה, שֶׁעַל יְדֵי סֵפֶר הַיְצִירָה בָּרְאוּ גֹּלֶם כִּתְמוּנַת אִשָּׁה. ‏